# What's the difference between resolving WPAD in process and out of process?

Tags: winapi, winhttp, pac, autoproxy

In the WinHTTP autoproxy API, the [WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_OPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will accept flags for WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_RUN_INPROCESS and WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_RUN_OUTPROCESS_ONLY.  What's the difference between these two flags and when would you use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.  The out-of-process approach uses the WinInet service, which is deemed more secure.  [While MSDN doesn't say so explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this is presumably because the in-proc option means the PAC's execution shares the same app context.